# VbScript/ASP Classic good OOP Pattern

Tags: object-oriented, vbscript, asp-classic

I have to create a website in Classic ASP, and I really want to do a clean design so I will try to put everything in Classes and Models to emulate the ViewModel Pattern.

So can you tell me if this approach of creating objects is good because I will use it everywhere

```
Class User
    Public Name
    Public Adress
    Public Title
    Public Text 
    Public Rights 'ArrayList of Right objects

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
       Initialize
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
       Dispose
    End Sub

   Private Sub Initialize()
       Name    = ""
       Adress  = ""
       Title   = ""
       Text    = ""
       Set Rights = Server.CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") ' Arraylist .net
   End Sub

   Private Sub Dispose()      
   End Sub

End Class
```

---

```
Class Right

    Public Name

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Initialize
    End Sub

   Private Sub Class_Terminate()
       Dispose
   End Sub

   Private Sub Initialize()
       Name    = ""
   End Sub

   Private Sub Dispose()      
   End Sub
End Class
```

---

And then I do this for instantiating objects :

```
Dim myUser 
Set myUser = New User

'Do some work

Set myUser = nothing 'Dispose the object
```

Any idea, suggestion or correction is welcome.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the supplied code.

Comment: it's missing something.....Semicolons....jk

Answer (score 2):

I am not a big VB person, but I would think that if you give your class a Dispose method you should use it rather than setting it to nothing, I know this is kind of the same thing, but if you aren't going to use the Method don't create the method, it's extra stuff.  if you are going to use it in the future, comment to that effect.

```
'This Method is for future development
Private Sub Dispose()
End Sub
```

OR

```
'TODO: Implement!
Private Sub Dispose()
End Sub
```

my comment syntax is probably off a little bit.

Comment: Yeah, like `'''TODO: Crea Dispose Method.` should read `'TODO: Implement!!`

Comment: I was trying to do the xml comment or whatever it is. so it alerts you that there is something left to do

Comment: I don't think there's such a fancypants thing in VBScript :)

Comment: well I was thinking ASP.NET....lol

Answer (score 1):

That's very nice & tidy, if you write all your code as cleanly, I want to debug your code!!

That said I might be wrong, but I don't think there's a *Dispose pattern* in VBScript (that's not .net!), but I see what you're trying to accomplish and it's excellent - use that method to set all your resources to `Nothing`.

The only thing I'd warmly recommend, is to use the `vbNullString` constant instead of `""` - `vbNullString` takes 0 bytes of memory, which isn't the case for `""`.

Comment: I changed the Tag from vbscript to vb.net because of the wording of the question I thought that he was probably writing in vb.net and not vbscript